# checkbox doesn't (check/uncheck) work inside bootstrap tab-pane

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Simple checkbox doesn't work inside tab-pane:
http://jsfiddle.net/68RXP/22/

Does anybody know why it doesn't work?
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11955861/1478467 - [solution (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/25/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case I'm the only one who thinks this is the same question as [twitter bootstrap tabs: links in content-panes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11955861/1478467)

---

The attribute `data-toggle="tab"` should only be put on the link (or button) that toggles the tab, not the tab itself.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/25/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... couldn't get it working using the solution above. Noticed the code was the same as mine, with the exception I was doing what is said on bootstrap's page, regarding tab activation:

"Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually):"

`$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
 })`

Removed this call in the JS file and it magically started to check the box. Tabs still working.
Took a better read at that same page and stated I was doing extra stuff, which was unnecessary. Check you aren't doing the same.